# AngularJS - stepping through array within the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

```
angular.forEach($scope.lista, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  $scope.listaCliente = data.listaClienteMaquina;
  console.log($scope.listaCliente);
});
```

being that when I access the array of $ scope.listaCliente, it returns undefined, someone help me? : /

Comment: Also add the array `$scope.lista`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating all of the properties of the object `$scope.lista` instead of the array collection `listaClienteMaquina`.

You can test it here http://codepen.io/leandroh/pen/RPgvwP

Avoid `$watch` and use `ng-change`.

Details in this post http://www.benlesh.com/2013/10/title.html

Answer (score 1):

> being that when I access the array of $scope.listaCliente, it returns undefined

One thing I am sure of is if `$scope.listaCliente` is an array then you need to push into it. Currently you are reassigning it every-time your loop runs.

```
$scope.listaCliente.push(data.listaClienteMaquina);
```

I hope you also initialized the `array` outside like

```
$scope.listaCliente = [];
```

Comment: when I use console.log (data), it just right shows the objects and the listaClienteMaquina array and what's in it, but when I put console.log (data.listaClienteMaquina), it returns undefinied

Comment: @LucasPadilha Can you add the content of your data in your question.